# Import a list of pairs into python

Tags: python, list, save

I have a file of the form:

```
{{ 1 , string1 }
 { 2 , string2 }
 ...
 { 1000 , string1000}}
```

The first field is always an integer and the second is a string (they can contain spaces). I would like to import this into Python (as a list of lists). What's the easiest way to achieve this? If it requires minor editing of the file that's fine (eg replacing the {braces} with [brackets] etc).

Comment: You should absolutely not use some bespoke format, rather, use an established supported format, like JSON. Then you can just sue the `json` module. Here, even CSV would work, so `1,string1` etc (no brackets... why are there brackets?)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga There are brackets because of where I got the list from. I can delete them. I tried to convert it to json but you seemingly can't use non-string values for the keys.

Comment: "There are brackets because of where I got the list from." what does that mean, exactly? In any case, you don't *want* keys, you want a list of lists, so the corresponding JSON sound be a json array of json arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can try `re` module (maybe it needs minor adjustments - depending on exact structure of file):

```py
import re

out = []
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for n, s in re.findall(
        r"(\d+)\s*,\s*(.*?)\s*\}\}?$", f_in.read(), flags=re.M
    ):
        out.append([int(n), s])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, "string1"], [2, "string2"], [1000, "string1000"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can easily remove all the braces at the start and end of the lines then you can use the csv module:

```
import csv

with open("list.csv") as csvfile:
            rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
            res = list(rows)
```

(PS to mods: should I delete this question? I went to do so but because it has an answer I got a warning that deleting answered questions could get me blocked.)